# Offline reverse geocoding on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

There are lots of existing questions relating to this issue, but I have looked at as many of them as I could find and did not get an answer.

I'm trying to perform an offline reverse geocoding lookup on iOS based on a latitude and longitude. I'd like to be able to provide a latitude and longitude, and be provided with the country in which that point lies. I can do this with Geonames (such as: http://api.geonames.org/countryCode?lat=45.03&lng=8.2&username=demo), but I need a similar ability offline, without Internet functionality on the device.

`CLLocation` does not provide offline services that work reliably enough for what I'm doing, it relies on caches made while you were previously online, etc. Messy.

I've tried this: https://github.com/drodriguez/reversegeocoding but haven't had any luck, it requires some slightly complex / confusing Terminal installations using something called Thor which I've never heard of, and was throwing up a variety of errors, so I bailed on it.

I've found a few downloadable maps, but these seem to be even more complicated, and worryingly, hundreds of megabytes or even gigabytes in size – much beyond the scope of an iOS app. I only need countries, nothing smaller than that (cities, streets, locations, etc.) so I think I should be able to get a much smaller file.

So my key question is: is there some pre-existing database or tool, preferably with iOS support, that I can feed a latitude/longitude, and get a country? And, if not, what steps should I take to get such functionality working on my own?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If that would be enough for what your app does, you can approximate the lookup with the locations of the airports (see http://www.openflights.org/data.html) or cities (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_by_longitude)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ReverseGeocodeCountry` is a simple lightweight offline country reverse geocoder for iOS, it has a static JSON file with country polygon data that is used to reverse geocode any lat/lng:

https://github.com/krisrak/ios-offline-reverse-geocode-country

Comment: This looks very promising – this is an old project I was working on but you may have just given me a reason to re-visit it! :)

Comment: do you know about an offline "city" reverse geocoder or if you have a city polygon data

Comment: you have find data and replace in json file, i found US cities on google search, i'm sure its all out there

Answer (score 1):

The "[Countries of the World](http://opengeocode.org/download/cow.php)" is a `.csv` text file with countries, coordinates, localised country names, capitals and other information. It seems to be free to use. You just have to import it into an SQLite database.

**Edit** Just noticed you want *reverse* geocoding. The database would only be good for *forward* geocoding.

You can download shapefiles for all countries at http://www.gadm.org/download. If you download a `.kmz`, you can unpack it to a list of coordinates for the borders. You could probably take every 5th or 10th coordinate to get smaller size (with less accuracy).

Comment: If it has maximum and minimum latitude and longitudes for all countries, it should do what I need, shouldn't it? I just throw those values into a data structure of some sort, then query it when the user taps on the map in my app?

Comment: It wouldn't be accurate enough for border regions. Think of France's border. You'll get huge sections of Belgium, Germany and The Netherlands in the North-East section. You're going to have to deal with shapefiles for country borders instead.

Comment: Oh, so this will basically draw a rectangle around the country's most northern, southern, western, and eastern points? That might not be awful, there won't be much cause for people to be clicking around borders, they're choosing a country from the whole world. With regard to the shapefiles, how might I proceed there? I've literally never done anything like this be fore.

Comment: I added some detail to the answer. I've never actually used shapefiles, but you'll get a list of coordinates along the border. From there I'm afraid you're on your own.

Comment: If you don't want to go to all this trouble, find the center coordinates for each country from the "Countries of the World", then present the user with a choice of 5-10 countries, ordered by distance. Most of the time their country will be in the first 3.

Comment: That's not a bad idea, at least initally. I'll give these a go, thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case I can suggest another good written offline geocoding library.
https://github.com/Alterplay/APOfflineReverseGeocoding

Comment: This one has the nicest API of the alternatives posted here.