# Reverse Geocode using GPS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, gps

I am finding current `latitude` and `longitude` using `GPS` **(without internet)**.

Now i want to implement `reverse geocoding` using that latitude and longitude through GPS without internet.

I have successfully implemented reverse geocoding with internet connection.

**This is my implemented code:-**

```
CLGeocoder * geoCoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation:newLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

    NSString * location = ([placemarks count] > 0) ? [[placemarks objectAtIndex:0] locality] : @"Not Found";

    CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *MyAddress = @"";
    MyAddress = [[placemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"] componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
    NSLog(@"address is %@", MyAddress);
}];
```

I have searched about this but could not find any solution.

How can i do this?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14588778/offline-reverse-geocoding-on-ios same as your question

Comment: The answer to that question isn't a great one just FYI.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot without internet , because this method (`reverseGeocodeLocation: completionHandler:`) submits the specified location data to the `geocoding server` asynchronously and returns.

Read the `CLGeocoder Class Reference` for that [CLGeocoder class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/Reference/Reference.html).

And if you think about it you'll need to have a database in order to get an address , where should it gather that information if not from a remote database.

Answer (score 0):

See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4419113/2446155

any of the methods mentioned there will work. Keep in mind that openstreetmap.org will only let you download small portions of data at a time. Cloudmate.com lets you download large amounts of data at once, but it will make your application VERY large.

You could also consider downloading and storing all the `CLGeocoder` Data for a specific area around the user over wifi and then be able to use it without Internet, but I'm not sure if that's possible.